# Test R app via openCPU localy

Tags: r, opencpu

I wrote an R package and now I want to provide let's say a small demo fronted as a webapplication. For this I already wrote a index.html file which I saved to the `<pkgRoot>/inst/www/` folder. I also installed the opencpu package which works fine wehen I use it via the `localhost:<portNum>/ocpu/test/` "Interface", where I already can see my Package and use the Ajax POST and GET requests in order to see the package is doing what it's ment to do.

But now im stuck in a sense that I do not know how to test my own app (index.html) localy. 
`localhost:<portNum>/ocpu/<pkgName>/www/index.html` does not work.
As I understood it, the opencpu Comes with the Apache 2 and hence ist not neccessary to set up an additional webserver?
When I check the path to the installed package the `www` folder as well as the index.html seem to be exactly were they should be, as far as I understand it.

Do i somehow have to install the app via the

```
opencpu::install_apps("pkgName")
```

inside R? Becaue if I try to do this, it seems there is no way to install local apps but only apps hosted at github. 
.... and I just want to test the app localy!

Realy happy for any suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use

```
opencpu::ocpu_start_app("pkgName")
```

That should start an HTTP server in R and launch your browser.