# Authoring OpenCPU-Apps on Cloud Server without github?

Tags: r, opencpu

After setting up an OpenCPU-Server and some first steps in this framework, I'm now looking forward to writing my first OpenCPU App and have already composed a package for this. As [this blog post](https://www.opencpu.org/posts/scoring-engine/) states:

> By including web pages in the /inst/www/ directory of the source package, we can turn our scoring engine into a standalone web application

Surely there must be more to it than this?

`> opencpu::installed_apps() # R-Studio Serverside, doesn't list my package
[1] "rwebapps/gitstats"    "rwebapps/markdownapp" "rwebapps/nabel"`

I've looked into `?opencpu::ocpu_start_app()` and `?opencpu::install_apps()` where it says

> [...] To deploy your apps on a cloud server or ocpu.io, simply push them to
>   github and install the opencpu webhook.

So my question is: Is there a way to both author and install OpenCPU Apps directly in R-Studio serversided, without first having to push my package to github?

Comment: For direct execution of the OpenCPU app see https://stackoverflow.com/a/50969279/8416610. In principle you could also do this on your cloud server. However, the more normal way would be to install Apache with the necessary extensions.

Answer (score 0):

You only need Github to deploy apps on the public cloud server: https://cloud.opencpu.org/ocpu/apps/

If you run your own opencpu cloud server, you can install your R package the usual way. Depending on how you installed it, it will be available under `/ocpu/apps` or `/ocpu/lib` or `/ocpu/user/yourname/lib`.